# using the value of an variable as an array name in php?

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

Evening all.
I have an array of possible get variables, which I am using to include external arrays. (aArray.php contains an array named a)

```
$options = array ("a","b","c");
$all=array();

foreach($options as $getVariable) 
    {
    if (isset($_GET[$getVariable])) {

        include($getVariable . "Array.php");
        array_push($all, ????); 
        }
    }
```

it's working fine up to the include.  My problem is the array_push.  Is there any way to render out the value of $getVariable and use it as a variable? (for example, after including $a, I want to add it to $all)

Comment: What is in `aArray.php` file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either have your included files look like this.

```
<?php

$myVars = ['foo' => 'bar'];
```

And then use `array_push($all, $myVars);`

Or

If your included files look like this.

```
<?php

return ['foo' => 'bar'];
```

Then you could use `array_push($all, include($getVariable . "Array.php"));`

Either way, `$all` would == `[['foo' => 'bar']]`